# StreamPlot colors giving wrong impression

Tags: plotting, color, visualization, perception

Here we have a streamplot where the intensity of the vector field is symmetrical with respect to a reflection about the x-axis:

```
Block[{a = 1, plotRange = 3, E0 = 0.5},
    StreamPlot[Evaluate[
        Grad[E0 z (1 - a^3/(z^2 + x^2)^(3/2)), {x, z}]
        ],
        {x, -plotRange, plotRange},
        {z, -plotRange, plotRange},
    RegionFillingStyle -> None,
    StreamStyle -> Thick,
    StreamColorFunctionScaling -> None,
    StreamPoints -> Fine,
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, z}, x^2 + z^2 > a^2],
    RegionBoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black}
        
    ]
 ]
```

However, because the streams are colored from their base and not their tips, the plot gives the wrong impression that the vector field is stronger on top of the circle than it is on the bottom. Is there a way we can correct for this effect to give a more perceptually faithful plot? Maybe color the streams from their middle rather than their bases?
[image]

Comment: 0

Sorry - not an answer to your question but just asking to clarify: your post states that the function is symmetric about the x axis but the plot seems to show that perhaps the magnitude is symmetric but not the direction? Is that correct and if so, does it matter?

Comment: @jmm yes, you are right that it is only the magnitude. The default stream color function depends only on magnitude so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: `StreamScale -> None` gives a better coloring but you lose the arrows. (`Arrow` does not implement `VertexColors` as far as I know.) `VectorPlot[]` with the options `VectorPoints -> Coarse, StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamScale -> None` gets the information into a plot, but it's not particularly pretty. Maybe you could use `StreamDensityPlot`? Can't say I was happy with anything I tried.

Comment: @MichaelE2 For irrotational fields like this one I overlay with a contour plot of the scalar potential; higher density of contours indicating larger field strength.